# Encounter an error on security exception being thrown in JAAS login module

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaas

I have a JAAS project which consist of RolePrincipal.java, UserPrincipal.java, and JaasLoginModule.java in place as shown in thte bottom of this question. This project was run in `Tomcat 6` and have the Realm configure in `context.xml` like following put inside META-INF folder:

```
<Context>
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm" 
            appName="JaasLoginModule"
            userClassNames="org.huahsin.RolePrincipal"
            roleClassNames="org.huahsin.UserPrincipal"/>
</Context>
```

In order to run this project, I need a jaas.conf like this:

```
JaasLoginModule {
    org.huahsin.JaasLoginModule required debug=true;
};
```

put under the project workspace and the following line into JVM argument when launching Tomcat from Eclipse:

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config="/home/huahsin/workspace/Jaas4/jaas.config"
```

Now when I execute this, I have following error shown in my console:

```
WARNING: Login exception authenticating username "user123"
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Security Exception
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:856)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:580)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm.authenticate(JAASRealm.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm.authenticate(JAASRealm.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:181)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:528)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:857)
    ... 17 more
```

The weird thing was the authentication has pass the `login()` but failed to proceed at `subject.getPrincipals().add(userPrincipal);` in JaasLoginModule.java. I am running out of clue how I could proceed with this issue?

---

**RolePrincipal.java**

```
public class RolePrincipal implements Principal {

    private String name;

    public RolePrincipal(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**UserPrincipal.java**

```
public class UserPrincipal implements Principal {

    private String name;

    public UserPrincipal(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**JaasLoginModule.java**

```
public class JaasLoginModule implements LoginModule {

    private CallbackHandler handler;

    private Subject subject;

    private String loginName;

    private List<String> userGroups;

    private UserPrincipal userPrincipal;

    private RolePrincipal rolePrincipal;

    @Override
    public void initialize(Subject subject, CallbackHandler callbackHandler,
            Map<String, ?> sharedState, Map<String, ?> options) {

        handler = callbackHandler;
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean login() throws LoginException {

        Callback[] callbacks = new Callback[2];
        callbacks[0] = new NameCallback("User Name:");
        callbacks[1] = new PasswordCallback("Password:", true);

        try {
            handler.handle(callbacks);

            String username = ((NameCallback) callbacks[0]).getName();
            String password = String.valueOf(((PasswordCallback) callbacks[1]).getPassword());

            if( username != null && username.equals("user123") &&
                    password != null && password.equals("pass123") ) {

                loginName = username;
                userGroups = new ArrayList<String>();
                userGroups.add("admin");

                return true;
            }

            throw new LoginException("Authentication Failed.");
        }
        catch( IOException e ) {
            throw new LoginException(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch( UnsupportedCallbackException e ) {
            throw new LoginException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean commit() throws LoginException {

        userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(loginName);
        subject.getPrincipals().add(userPrincipal);

        if( userGroups != null && userGroups.size() > 0 ) {
            for( String groupName : userGroups ) {
                rolePrincipal = new RolePrincipal(groupName);
                subject.getPrincipals().add(rolePrincipal);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean abort() throws LoginException {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean logout() throws LoginException {

        subject.getPrincipals().remove(rolePrincipal);
        subject.getPrincipals().remove(userPrincipal);

        return true;
    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app ...>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Admin</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
  </security-role>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Admin Realm</realm-name>
  </login-config>
</web-app>
```